# Visual studio to show function @ main.cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to figure out why VS2012 doesn't show the function **multi** from functions.cpp @ main.cpp. in order to get it displayed in main.cpp I have to type **int multi();** in main.cpp.

Here's 2 screenshots, the first screenshots is with `int multi();`in main.cpp

the second one is without. The code runs fine in 2 of the cases, but when I want to navigate to `multi` function in main.cpp file, I can't do it if I don't type `int multi();` @ main.cpp

Can someone please explain me what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you.

Example image 1

[image]

Example image 2

[image]

Here's my code

Main.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int plus();

int main()
{

cout << "Eneter a number you want to multiply" << endl;
cout << multi() <<endl;
cout << randomNumber << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Header.h

```
#ifndef _HEADER_
#define _HEADER_

#include <iostream>

int randomNumber = 4;
int multi ();

#endif
```

functions.cpp

```
#ifndef _HEADER_
#define _HEADER_

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int multi()
{
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    return(x=x+x);
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because that dropdown list only shows names of items that you declare/define in the current file. That's the intended behavior, because its purpose is navigation within the current file, and showing names of items in other files would take you to different files (plus it would show you things in headers like iostream, which you are not really interested in).

Other features of IntelliSense do show you the "multi" function, like typing "::":

[image]

Comment: Thank you! If I understand it right, if I'm using an external file to declare/define my functions, I'll still have to do a forward declare/define my functions in the file where I'm going to call/use these functions. correct?

Comment: No! You just have to include the header where they're declared/defined. The fact that the dropdown list at the top doesn't show them doesn't mean they're not available. And like I said, other features of IntelliSense do show them.

Comment: Thank you! You helped me to understand the programing language a bit more and the tool. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use only with the header file, and do that like this:

```
#ifndef _HEADER_H
#define _HEADER_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int randomNumber = 4;

int multi()
{
    int x = 1;
    cin >> x;
    return(x=x+x);
}

#endif
```

and with this way you don't need declare the function.
what you tried to do is create a 'class' file ?
better to you its just click right button on your project > Add > Class
and you can see how it works.

Answer (score -1):

Include guards, the `#ifndef _HEADER_, #define _HEADER_, #endif` lines don't belong in cpp files under normal circumstances.  You should remove them from `functions.cpp`.

It may not cause you issues in a small program, but `header.h` and `_HEADER_` are poor choices for names.  You shouldn't use an underscore followed by a capital letter.  More info here: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)